# Can scala splat be used for anything that isn't a varargs?

Tags: scala, splat, unroll

given e.g:

```
scala> def pipes(strings:String*) = strings.toList.mkString("|")
```

which I can call normally:

```
scala> pipes("foo", "bar")
res1: String = foo|bar
```

or with a splat:

```
scala> val args = List("a","b","c")
scala> pipes(args:_*)
res2: String = a|b|c
```

But can I use a splat to provide arguments for anything but a varargs parameter? e.g I would like to do something like:

```
scala> def pipeItAfterIncrementing(i:Int, s:String) = (i + 1) + "|" + s
scala> val args:Tuple2[Int, String] = (1, "two")
scala> pipeItAfterIncrementing(args:_*)
```

That doesn't work, but is there any way to achieve the same effect of providing multiple arguments from a single object, whether it be a tuple or something else? Is there any reason this couldn't be implemented for tuples, given that both their length and types are known at compile-time?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `Function.tupled` to do exactly this: turn a function that takes *n* arguments into a function that takes a single tuple argument of arity *n*. As can be expected, `Function.untupled` does the reverse job.

The special type ascription `: _*` is only applicable for repeated parameter (a.k.a. varargs).

```
scala> def pipeItAfterIncrementing(i:Int, s:String) = (i + 1) + "|" + s
pipeItAfterIncrementing: (i: Int,s: String)java.lang.String

scala> def tupledPipeItAfterIncrementing = Function.tupled(pipeItAfterIncrementing _)
tupledPipeItAfterIncrementing: ((Int, String)) => java.lang.String

scala> val args:Tuple2[Int, String] = (1, "two")
args: (Int, String) = (1,two)

scala> tupledPipeItAfterIncrementing(args)
res0: java.lang.String = 2|two
```

Answer (score 13):

Well kind of ...

```
scala> def pipeItAfterIncrementing(i:Int, s:String) = (i + 1) + "|" + s
scala> val args:Tuple2[Int, String] = (1, "two")
scala> (pipeItAfterIncrementing _).tupled(args)
```

will give you the desired `2|two`.

Comment: You are allowed (and encouraged) to upvote multiple answers. Just 'accepting' is reduced to one answer.

Comment: Plus, your answer also shows that `tupled` is also a method on `Function` instances in addition to the one on the `Function` object.

Comment: @JPP, that and your's didn't have the example yet when I saw it after posting mine ;-)

Comment: @subsub Right, I was editing it at the same time… Looks like the first few minutes are busy times :)